# How to trim characters from a string in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a value like "RWCE RU Regional" in an attribute and I need only first four characters I.e the output should be "RWCE"

Answer (score 2):

Use [subtring](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) function.

```
SUBSTR('RWCE RU Regional',1,4) should do.
```